# Get Unique ID of Android Device?

Tags: android

I have htc one b model android phone. I want to know my device ID. I do not know how could I finding out my device ID .

Comment: go to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id?rq=1)

Comment: [This library](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-BaseLib) provides a unique ID per device with [Identity.getDeviceId(context)](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-BaseLib/blob/master/Source/src/im/delight/android/baselib/Identity.java) and an identifier for your app installation via [Identity.getInstallationId(context)](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-BaseLib/blob/master/Source/src/im/delight/android/baselib/Identity.java).

Answer (score 18):

Try this :

```
    String deviceId = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
            Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    Toast.makeText(this, deviceId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

*android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID*

A 64-bit number (as a hex string) that is randomly generated on the device’s first boot and should remain constant for the lifetime of the device.

Source Link : http://blog.vogella.com/2011/04/11/android-unique-identifier/

**Note** :  *The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device.*

Comment: This is not exact. This ID might change upon rooting phone, and also upon doing a "factory reset".

So, this could be used - but do not count on it.

Comment: I just want to check my phone device ID.how to check this

Comment: @gilonm : Yes that's true and its also mentioned in the link.

Comment: @user3736827 : There is no specific deviceId concept, you need to check the unique string that identifies your phone like the one mentioned in the answer or you can use IMEI number.

Comment: @Siddharth Oh, just saw this link now.. I simply had this problem a couple weeks ago...

Comment: @gilonm : I have also edited my answer and added a note on that point.

Comment: @Siddharth I saw that.. Cheers!

Comment: will this ID change upon OS update?

Comment: @HendraAnggrian : Yes

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
TelephonyManager TM = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

// IMEI No.
String imeiNo = TM.getDeviceId();

// IMSI No.
String imsiNo = TM.getSubscriberId();

// SIM Serial No.
String simSerialNo  = TM.getSimSerialNumber();

// Android Unique ID
String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Don't forget to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

to your manifest file.

Comment: hello sir I am confused by answer....I just want to check unique ID of my htc phone....but how could i do this...everybody give me link and code to check id......but i dont know how to implement this...please tell me in brief

Comment: Hi, the thing is, a "unique ID" could mean many different things depending on the context and on your specific situation. The [official Android blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html) recommends that you use the ANDROID_ID, which is the fourth option above in my code and which is supposedly the least risk-prone option. Just keep in mind that the ANDROID_ID is reset each time the user performs a factory-reset, so you may want to take this into consideration for how it may impact your app.

Comment: doesn't work, error 'ANDROID_ID cannot be resolved or is not a field'

Comment: @ShirishHerwade: apologies, its in the **Settings.Secure** package. I've edited the answer, can you please try it now ?

Comment: already tried that, :) it worked. But thanks for your time

Comment: @ZygoteInit yes I would like to do that if my problem gets solved; but the issue is i'm using this device no to download apk using chrome extension, but its giving error... and i'm not able to download apk, so my problem still not fixed. By the way, thanks for your time and help. and so I have upvote the answer already. But hey... its not my question so can't accept

Comment: @Y.S , Please help me on it, I want to get the ID of the device, which even not changed when device is rooted or wiped out. What could be possible solution of it?

Comment: I would like to, when you're using "READ_PHONE_STATE" permission make sure to ask this permission to user at runtime as this permission is categorized as "Dangerous permission" in official doc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: is there any other way to check phone unique id like in setting